# How to edit a specific line of a text file with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am clueless of how to do this, I am trying to edit the second line of a text file imported in html. This is my code so far:

```
let AddedItems = '';
function GenerateCode() {
    const Out = document.getElementById("Output").value
    const Quantity = document.getElementById("OutQuantity").value
    const Time = document.getElementById("Time").value
    if(Quantity < 1) return alert('You need to set a quantity greater than 0');
    if(Time < 0) return alert('You need to set a time of aleast 0');
    if(Out === '') return alert('You need to set a output item');
    document.getElementById("CodeOut").innerHTML = ',{"itemId": "' + Out + '", "quantity": ' + Quantity + ', "craftTime": ' + Time + ', "ingredientList": [' + AddedItems + ']}';
}
function ResetItems() {
    AddedItems = '';
    GenerateCode();
}
function AddItem() {
    const ItemQ = document.getElementById("IimeQ").value;
    const Input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
    if(ItemQ < 1) return alert('You need to set a quantity greater than 0');
    if(Input === '') return alert('You need to set a input');
    if(AddedItems === '') {
        AddedItems = '{ "quantity": ' + ItemQ + ', "itemId": "' + Input + '"}';
    } else {
    AddedItems = AddedItems.concat(', { "quantity": ' + ItemQ + ', "itemId": "' + Input + '"}');
    }
    GenerateCode();
}
```

it is just calling functions when a button is clicked, but I need another function to get a text file and  change the second to last line to "document.getElementById("CodeOut").innerHTML"

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're doing anything with a text file from scanning the code, since you're reading elements in from the DOM. Can you give an example of the element you're interacting with?

Comment: The element is:  <input type="file" id="File">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [FileReader API](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-a-local-text-file-using-javascript/) and pass the data from the file input. You can then split by line breaks and read it in as an array (if the file isn't massive, otherwise you should use some sort of a buffer)

```
    document.getElementById('inputfile').addEventListener('change', function() { 
        const fr=new FileReader(); 
        fr.onload=function(){ 
            document.getElementById('output') 
                    .textContent=fr.result; 
        } 
          
        let text = fr.readAsText(this.files[0]); 
        /*Split by a regex that looks at windows (\n) 
        and unix (\r) line breaks, then get the second line.*/
        text.split(/[\r\n]+/g)[1];
    })
```

Comment: But then how would I get the value of the second to last line?

Comment: I can't, Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: @Evan_roos456 Thanks. You can check out the documentation for the FileReader API  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)